# Visual Studio 2015 installation does not include vb or javascript

Tags: javascript, python, vb.net, installation, visual-studio-2015

I had VS community edition 2015 with VB installed but I uninstalled it. I am trying to re-install it but it does not give me the option to select VB as a language. Only VC++, VF# and Python is available.
What am I doing wrong?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1Enp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is ok.. Visual Studio will automatically install the C#/VB for you..

refer this article : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2h7fzkw.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

[image]

*** Custom installation also will add the C# / VB along with your selected languages

Have a nice day!!

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I feel stupid because I am not successful. The website you refer to also states "Custom components include Visual C++, Visual F#, SQL Server Data Tools, Cross-platform mobile tools and SDKs, and third-party SDKs and extensions." VB is not mentioned. I did install VS 2015 previously and VB or C# was not included and I could not add them.

Comment: There also is no option to select Custom or Default

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled all the Visual Studio components (it takes hours) and reinstalled VS 2015 community and all the languages were installed even though the installation features do not list VB, C# or Javescript. Maybe remnants of a previous install effected the re-installation.